# English version of ISO 3166-2 subdivision data

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table containing ISO 3166-2 location subdivision data.  The data contains non-English names with accent characters that I would prefer to have as English names/characters.

Examples include:

```
'Ajmān
Ghōr
Kāpīsā
Abū Z̧aby [Abu Dhabi]
```

As you can see with the last example, there are instances which contain square brackets with the English name.

Any ideas where I can find such a version with English names and characters/no-accents?

Answer (score 1):

http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

has (or used to have) asciiname names and "alternatenames".  The latter is a list of names, often in a variety of languages.  Here are the alternatenames for Abu Dabi:

A-pu-that-pi,AEbu Saby,AUH,Aboe Dhabi,Abou Dabi,Abu Dabi,Abu Dabis,Abu Daby,Abu Daibi,Abu Dhabi,Abu Dhabi emiraat,Abu Zabi,Abu Zaby,Abu Zabye,Abu Zabyo,Abu Ḍabi,Abu Ḑabi,Abu-Dabi,Abu-Dabi khot,Abu-Dabio,Abu-Dzabi,Abú Dabí,Abú Daibí,Abú Zabí,Abû Daby,Abū Dabī,Abū Z̧aby,Abū Z̧abye,Abū Z̧abyo,Abū Z̧abī,Ampou Ntampi,Ebu Dabi,Ebu Dhabi,Gorad Abu-Dabi,a bu zha bi,abu dhabi,abu-dabi,abudabi,abudhabi,abw zby,abwzby,aputapi,xa bud abi,Â-pu-tha̍t-pí,Äbu Saby,Əbu-Dabi,Άμπου Ντάμπι,Αμπου Νταμπι,Αμπού Ντάμπι,Абу Даби,Абу-Даби,Абу-Даби хот,Абу-Дабі,Горад Абу-Дабі,Әбу-Даби,Աբու Դաբի,אבו דאבי,أبوظبي,ئەبووزەبی,ابو ظبى,ابوظبی,ابوظہبی,अबु धाबी,अबू धाबी,আবুধাবি,ਅਬੂ ਧਾਬੀ,ଆବୁଧାବି,அபுதாபி,ಅಬು ಧಾಬಿ,അബുദാബി,අබුඩාබි,อาบูดาบี,ཨ་པོའུ་དྷ་པེ།,အဘူဒါဘီမြို့,აბუ-დაბი,አቡ ዳቢ,アブダビ,阿布扎比,아부다비

The table is over 1GB when loaded into MySQL.  I think I downloaded it in 2016.  If you need some tips on getting around hiccups in the loading, let me know.

Ghor and Kapisa are in the table but without the macron accents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, looking at the provided resource, the number of different zip files is somewhat confusing.  I found a simpler solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the data from https://www.ip2location.com/free/iso3166-2

This data in CSV format contains subdivision names without the accents with separate columns for country_code and subdivision_code.  There are however apostrophes in the subdivision names which are easily removed using the replace function.

Note: the subdivision codes are prefixed with the country_code and a hyphen.  If you want just the subdivision code on its own, then use the data -> Text to Columns function in Excel and separate on the hyphen.  Make sure that you make the resulting subdivision code column with text format to retain any leading zeros.  The replace function in Excel won't work as text format is ignored by Excel!